# How to get total only from items that have been saved to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails app I have `invoices` which can have many nested `items`.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :date, :number, :items_attributes

  has_many :items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items

  def total
    items.map(&:total).sum
  end

end
```

How can I make sure the `total` is only calculated on `items` that have actually been saved to the database?

Right now, my `total` also includes `items` which have merely been instantiated in my `new` view but not yet saved to the database.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `total` a numeric field in the `items` table?

Comment: @Stefan: No, it's being calculated off the item's `price` and `quantity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def total
  items(true).map(&:total).sum
end
```

The `true` forces an reload of the `items`. Or:

```
def total
  items.select(&:persisted?).map(&:total).sum
end
```

`persisted?` is `true`, if the object is in the database (not new, not deleted).

Comment: I would add a parameter `persisted_only` for total (default to true) so in cases where you want to know the total of all line items rather than those in the database. For example if you have an error when updating the invoice its handy to know the expected total.